# youtube-dl :: how to listen to audio while downloading

Tags: python, tcp, youtube, udp, youtube-dl

I know that I can download an audio track from YouTube through this easy command:

```
youtube-dl -f 251 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRIF4_WzU1w'
```

Lately YouTube has been slowing down the download speed.

Is there a way I can listen to the audio while downloading the track?

Where is the file located while it is downloading? On the RAM?

Comment: I am a bit surprised that the bounty isn't automatically given to me following your acceptation of my answer... Could you give it to me please, as it seems that I solved your problem?

Comment: Hello @BenjaminLoison, I still have to wait 32 minutes: https://snipboard.io/NMe0bs.jpg :) . They should definitely automate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know when downloading a video while precising `-f 251` it is being written while downloading in `VIDEO_TITLE.webm.part` and at the end of the download this file is rename `VIDEO_TITLE.webm`.

To listen to the audio of a video while downloading its track, just open in a web-browser the second URL returned by:

```
youtube-dl -g 'HRIF4_WzU1w'
```

If you are also interested in having the audio file at the end of your listening, use your command or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in your web-browser.